# how to fill div over dropdown list, using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, xml

i have one issue. i made a html page, with a dropdown list, which is loaded from xml file (over jQuery). Now my problem is, how to - when i select certain item from my dropdown list, in some div under, it opens info about that item. this is html: http://pastebin.com/hVHWPdvM and this is xml im using: http://pastebin.com/3pVXVXpg . Now when for e.g. i click on "1" how to display a "TEXT1TEXT1TEXT1TEXT1TEXT1" in html div.

Big thanks,
Milos

Comment: You should post relevant code here and provide a jsfiddle

Comment: well its loaded from xml, and im not sure can i put xml in jsfiddle :\

Answer (score 1):

You could use `change`:

**HTML**

```
<select id="list">
    <option>Value</option>
    <option>Value 2</option>
    <option>Value 3 </option>
    <option>Value 4</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#list").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $("#content").html(val); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YVsZz/

Obviously you could change the `value` to the `XML` description content

Comment: hi, tryed ur code, but when i modify it it writes all whats under "<text></text>" whatever i click. its not only for specified item, its for all of them. e.g.: i click "1" and i get this "please make a selection first set1second set2" for all items in xml.

Answer (score 0):

jquery code:

```
$("#mySelect").change(function()
{
    $("#TextToWrite").text($(this).val());
})
```

this should fix your problem. just copy & use above code.

I have made few changes in your pastebin code. please combine both.

http://pastebin.com/3QVcWu5v

Comment: hi, tryed ur code, but when i modify it it writes all whats under "<text></text>" whatever i click. its not only for specified item, its for all of them.
e.g.: i click "1" and i get this "please make a selection first set1second set2" for all items in xml.

Comment: can you post the html code generated after completion of the ajax call from xml.

Comment: oh, sorry i dont think that i quite understood what you mean with that. all i did was that i entered your code and got all results for all values on any selected value ( it printed everything, no matter which value i picked ). :\ my point was more like, if i select value "1", then it prints only whats under <text></text> tags of that value, etc for all others separately on same way.

Comment: I have edited it. i think the issue was you are using my code as is. Now i have changed it as per the your requirement. Use it as is now.

Answer (score 0):

Please define the onclick event and xyz js function as mentioned below:

```
<form>
      <select id="mySelect" onchange="xyz();">
              <option>loading</option>
      </select>
</form>
<div id="TextToWrite"></div>
```

JS

```
function xyz() {
    $('#TextToWrite').html($('#mySelect').val());
}
```